# Server Side Rendering in Angular

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I folowed this tutorial and created the project as mentioned . But when trying to run the project using ng serve command or using the command npm run build:ssr 
throws the error as shown in the .https://blog.upstate.agency/how-to-build-an-angular-app-with-server-side-rendering-f7f415b851c8

[image]

Comment: Did you run npm install? what have you tried?

Comment: Yeah i tried running npm install

Comment: What happens when you run ng serve? which errors appear then?

Comment: The same error as in the above screenshot, only change is "cannot find module path" eroor line has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run "npm install" before executing "ng serve". After running npm install, if the same error exists then ur package.json doesnot contain the required modules.You have to install them manually.
eg: npm install fs

Comment: Even after running the fs install command it is throwing error for fs module. Path module worked fine and no more throwing error. Also the find name error is stil there. How to resolve these.

Comment: can u add the package.json here

Comment: {
  "name": "angular-universal-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },

Comment: <code>
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",

Comment: "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.20",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",

Comment: "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}

Comment: did u execute npm install path?

Comment: Yes i installed npm install path

Comment: delete ur node modules folder entirely and again execute npm install and c

Comment: Sure will do like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179659/ts2304-cannot-find-name-require-and-process

Comment: thanks a lot dude. it got complied successfully. Do you have idea on install node.js and implementing server side rendering? I have a project implemented in angular 2. But SEO is not proper. So to implement SEO i need to implement server side rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174380/discussion-between-user3292629-and-vjanu).