# cannot find name 'require' in angular 7(typescript 3.1.3)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, typescript3.0

My question is why this error shown?

> ERROR in src/app/p2p/p2p.component.ts(14,16): error TS2580: Cannot
>   find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?
>   Try `npm i @types/node`.

I have install

```
 @types/node
in app/tsconfig.app.json have add 
"types": [
    "node" 
  ],
  "typeRoots": [ 
  "../node_modules/@types"
 ]
```

but there is error cannot find 'require'

Comment: show your p2p.component.ts

Comment: declare var require : any;

export class P2pComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
   var Peer = require(peer)
   var p = new Peer({ initiator: location.hash === '#1', trickle: false }) 
   p.on('signal', function (data) {
   console.log('SIGNAL', JSON.stringify(data))
   document.querySelector('#outgoing').textContent = JSON.stringify(data)
 })
 document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()}) 
    p.on('connect', function () {
      console.log('CONNECT')
      p.send('whatever' + Math.random())
    })
   }



}

Answer (score 44):

The problem also remained after adding it to my tsconfig.json, but additionaly adding the following line to tsconfig.app.json resolved it for me:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
}
```

So be sure to add this into both files **./tsconfig.json** AND **./src/tsconfig.app.json** and it should work.

Comment: For me worked when I added it to ```tsconfig.app.json```! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found I could add `"node"` to `"types"` in `tsconfig.app.json` without also including it in `tsconfig.json` and the project compiled for me.

Comment: Winner! The problem is that a default tsconfig.app.json has an *empty* types property, which obliterates the one from tsconfig.json. Took me a while to work that out

Comment: This works for react or any typescript project

Comment: @DaveNottage input helped me, removing empty types from tsconfig.app.json and added types=["node"] in tsconfig.json fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 31):

Add the following settings to `src/tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Type node is missing

install @types/node :

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

or

```
yarn add @types/node
```

edit your `src/tsconfig.json` adding:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["node"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Like some other folks, I, too, had added node to the 'types' array in tsconfig and for some reason it made no difference.  Knowing full well that this is a hack, here's how I resolved it:

Add this line anywhere above the 'require' statement:
`declare const require: any;`

This is not a real fix, but I don't have the time to battle with this type of plumbing problem right now.  I'll come back and deal with it later (or probably not, but that's OK, too)

Comment: Did you get a proper solution mate?

Comment: No, never came back to revisit this

Answer (score 1):

check `tsconfig.json` too. you need to add the same settings there too.

Answer (score 1):

Its all because typeScript is not aware of the require keyword so 
do add a line making typescript aware of require keyword

once its compiled to javascript it knows the require word better and make the work done

```
declare var require: any;

const pokemon = require('src/assets/pokedex.json');
```