# Cannot find name 'Buffer' error after installing Tesseract.js in Angular

Tags: angular, tesseract, yarnpkg

I need Tesseract in my project so first I used `yarn add tesseract.js` after that I used `yarn add --dev @types/tesseract.js`. When I try to use `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/tesseract.js/src/index.d.ts:98:60 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

98     | CanvasRenderingContext2D | File | Blob | ImageData | Buffer;
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: facing the same issue. Any solution that worked?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding `types: ["node"]` to the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.app.json` file.

```js
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["node"] // <-- This should do the charm.
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solve mine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my tesseract application and I tried this and it worked.

Source:
[cannot find name 'require' in angular 7(typescript 3.1.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115665/cannot-find-name-require-in-angular-7typescript-3-1-3)

Comment: Hi Host_Ghost, thank you for spending the time to answer a question here. In SO, it is usual to provide (at least in summary) the actual solution and then add the source link. Makes your insight findable by the SO search